# MvcSiteMapProvider not generating correct URLs in dynamic nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, mvcsitemapprovider

I wrote a dynamic node provider that looks like so:

```
public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        var dictionaryDefs = from d in provider.GetDictionaries()
                                 orderby d.DisplayNamePlural
                                 select d;


        foreach (DictionaryInfo di in dictionaryDefs)
        {
            var newNode = new DynamicNode()
            {
                Title = di.DisplayNamePlural,
                Description = "Import " + di.DisplayNamePlural,
                ParentKey = "Import Records" 
            };

            newNode.Attributes.Add("entity",di.DictionaryName);

            yield return newNode;

        }
    }
```

My template node looks like (namespace and assembly names anonymized):

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title ="ToBeReplaced" route="CMS_EntityAction"   controller="ImportDictionary" action="Import"  crudlevel="Update" dynamicNodeProvider="NameSpace.INeedToImportDataNodeProvider, MyAssembly"/>
```

And here is the Route I specified for it to use:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "CMS_EntityAction", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{entity}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Grid", showCheckboxes = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { controller = @"(Grid|ImportDictionary)" }              
            );
```

Note that the dynamic node provider supplies the `entity` value, but the controller and action are to be inherited from the template.

All I get for Urls, though is "#", which from what I can tell in skimming the source, means the UrlResolver couldn't resolve the Url.

If I remove the specific route name from the template node (`route="CMS_EntityAction"`) then it just generates the same URL over and over again for each node which is `/ImportDictionary/Import` which is missing the `entity` value as the 3rd segment.

I've tried specifying the controller and action in the dynamic node provider instead of the template and I get the same thing, it just will not use the value of `entity` in creating the URL.

Any ideas of what I need to change, specify or fix? Thanks.

(Please don't judge me on that ShowCheckboxes thing, it's out of my hands :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not adding the "entity" to the RouteValues collection of the node, but you are instead adding it to Attributes, making it a custom attribute value. Custom attributes are not taken into consideration when generating the URL.

If you change:

```
newNode.Attributes.Add("entity",di.DictionaryName);
```

To:

```
newNode.RouteValues.Add("entity",di.DictionaryName);
```

Then the entity argument will be inserted into the URL.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking in terms of the XML representation, where everything starts as an attribute of the node. Didn't realize that doing it in code was "after" the attributes had been sorted between the two collections. Thanks.